# How do I identify if slow network is because of local network infrastructure

Tags: networking, proxy, wireshark

I have tried using wireshark and captured packets when I was downloading a file.
I would like to narrow down the problem to local infrastructure like proxy or the router.

I doubt the problem to be with the proxy server's bandwidth capability or the rules that append or modify headers, etc.

The round trip time seems to be having some anomaly values every now and then.

How do I narrow down to the local infrastructure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ping Plotter to help track down your problem. Just set the destination to goole.com  and it will give you more detailed information of the routing than a simple ping or traceroute. Also, Ping Plotter is not free, but it does have a trial version.

[Ping Plotter](http://www.pingplotter.com/)

Comment: Does ping go through a proxy? I suppose only http/https traffic go through a proxy

Comment: @Andrews ping uses ICMP, you can go into the ping plotter settings and change it to use TCP, which would then make it go through a proxy. But ping plotter is pretty good at identifying nodes etc.